# Dropdown Menu Hover LI Issue

Tags: jquery

This code is used for a dropdown menu, the issue is that when i hover over the li the dropdown opens fine and then when i moved the mouse over the new dropdown div the hover property of the li a is removed, I need the li a background to use the hover properties until the mouse moves away from the li a or dropdown div.

```
$("ul.nav li").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.dropdown').toggle();
});
```

This is the menu code I'm using.

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="first"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">CATEGORIES</a>
        <div class="dropdown" style="display: none">test</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not sure but seems like your .hover() function fires twice. Once on the parent, once on the children. So you toggle twice, you end up at ground zero, right? A solution could be to look for a CSS dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with just good ol' CSS. No need for jQuery.

```
.dropdown { display: none; }
.nav li:hover .dropdown { display: block; }
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PN8x9/)**

Comment: Even using this the 'li a' loses it's hover background property when I move the mouse over the dropdown box when it's displayed.

Comment: You might have a script in your code that's messing with the nav's behavior then. It's working fine in the fiddle I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the .hover function, use the mouseenter function tied to the "a" element to trigger the dropdown.

Then use the mouseleave function tied to the higher li element to hide the drop menu.